# Laravel Cookie doesn't get set

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies, axios

I'm trying to save an array as a json in a cookie, in the front-end there is a form which gets filled and it auto-saves every couple of minutes i want to save the data as a JSON in a cookie in case the user leaves the page.

In the controller i save the cookie like this:

```
public function autoSave() {

    $data = request()->validate([
        'data' => 'required'
    ]);


    $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;// one year

    $array = json_encode($data);

    Cookie::forget('listData'); //I use this to delete the old cookie and generate a new one


    $cookie = Cookie::make('listData', $array, $lifetime);

    return response()->json(['success' => true])->withCookie($cookie);


}
```

And i retrieve it like this:

```
public function getAutoSave() {

    if(Cookie::get('listData') !== null) {
        $data = Cookie::get('listData');

        $data = json_decode($data);
        

        return response()->json([
            'data' => $data
        ]);

    }
    else {

        return response()->json([
            'data' => false
        ]);

    }

}
```

Autosave some times work, some times it doesn't, what could be the problem?

**Edit

Looking at the server response i get an error `The Set-Cookie header had invalid syntax`, probably the JSON i'm trying to save as a cookie creates it because it is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i developed workaround and made the user register first before he can do any action in the form which in my case the registration was required just not at the start, i created a model-migration autosave with a relationship to the user and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using local storage on the client side for this? Seems like the perfect use case for it (unless i'm missing some context on why it should be a cookie). Plus, your wouldn't be making a trip to the server and back to save your data.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are meant to be exchanged with the browser.

From my understanding, you want to set a cookie when the request starts, and interact with the cookie newly created cookie before sending a response to the user.

Of course, you could hold a Cookie object in memory, but using Cookie::get to access cookies not sent in the request is not possible.

Cookie::get() will read cookies sent in the request
Cookie:: make() will just create a cookie object and not store it anywhere
Cookie:: queue() will just create a cookie object, and hold it in memory to be appended to the response, but this object won't be accessible from Cooke::get()
If you want to access data throughout the request I suggest:

Use the session to hold this data
Use the $request->attributes property
Create a repository object, and bind it as a singleton in the container, so always the same instance is resolved.
Note that "repository" here is just a reference for an object that holds data, it can be any object, such as an ArrayObject instance
An advantage of using a session, as it seems you want this data to be persisted between requests, is that the session is automatically persisted.

The other two methods are not persisted, and you will need to handle persistence yourself if you want the data to be shared across requests. Consider using middleware for that. But if that is the case I would consider using the session.

But none of these methods are accessible from the browser. If you need to send data to the browser, use one of the methods above to manipulate the data throughout the request and use middleware to write the data to a cookie before the response is sent.

Just for the record Cookie::make() only creates a cookie object in memory. It won´t automatically attach the cookie to the response and thus the cookie won't be sent automatically to the user's browser.

If you want to calla helper that already creates and attaches a cookie to the response, I guess you are after the Cookie::queue(...) method, as described in the docs section named "Attaching Cookies To Responses":

[Laravel-Cookie-Purpose-Handling](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#attaching-cookies-to-responses)

I really recommend reading Laravel documentation very closely. It is very well written and provide a lot of good insights.